# Vite: Bundle specific javascript files

Tags: javascript, webpack, vite

I have different javascript files. Forexample
`jQuery.js`
`owl.js`
`devil.js`
`swipper.js`
`manage.js`
`business.js` inside `src` directory.

NOTE: These files are not importing each other, So I have to manually specify the path that these are the javascript files which include `owl.js`, `swipper.js`, `devil.js` bundle them all in `public.min.js` and the bundled the remaining three files in `main.min.js`

Is there any way I can bundle them with vite.

**Update:**
I create this vite plugin which can you the exact the same thing
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-multi-bundler

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add `export default`to your src files or install plugins with npm and use it in your imports.
Create 2 extra files: `src/main.js`

```
import {jQuery} from 'jquery';
import manage from './manage.js';
import business from './business.js';

export default {
  jQuery,
  manage,
  business
};
```

and `src/public.js`:

```
import owl from './owl.js';
import swiper from 'swiper';
import devil from './devil.js';

export default {
  owl,
  swipper,
  devil
};
```

Use these files in `vite.config.js` input:

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    assetsDir: 'src',
    outDir: 'dist',
    build: {
      analyze: false,
      minify: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          main: 'src/main.js',
          public: 'src/public.js',
        },
        output: {
          inlineDynamicImports: false,
          format: 'es',
          entryFileNames: '[name].min.js',
          chunkFileNames: '[name]-[hash].min.js'
        }
      }
    },

  });
```

[See more](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-rollupoptions)